How do I stop a thread which calls a long running task from another python script?
I want to implement a GUI in which I start a long_running_task with a start button. While the task is running, I animate the status in the GUI. That's why I use multi-threading and create a thread for animation and the long_running_task in start_task().
Now I want to be able to abort the long_running_task while it's running. Therefore my start button switches to an abort button (update_button()), which updates a status variable self.running by clicking it.
Now I check that status variable in each iteration in the long_running_task, which is just an os.walk() to list all files in a very big directory.
If I have long_running_task() defined as a function in my class, the abort button works perfectly fine (just uncomment all commented lines of code to try it yourself).
My Problem is: In reality, my long_running_task has many lines of code. That's why I want to safe it in a separate python script. That's why I introduced and connected the function back_end() with the start button. It calls the long_running_task function from an other script, providing the status variable to it. This should work because if you pass a variable, you only reference the memory location, therefore the variable is always at the current value in the function as well. Nevertheless, if I call the function like that, my abort button doesn't stop the long_running_task anymore.
I'm working on a Windows Environment.
My code:
Main:
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import itertools
import time

from other_python_script import long_running_task

class APP():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Task Manager")

        self.running = False
        self.task_thread = None
        self.anim_thread = None
        self.status_var = tk.StringVar(value="Ready")

        self.directory = "Any directory with great depth"
        
        self.status_label = ttk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.status_var)
        self.status_label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.start_abort_button = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Start", command=self.start_task)
        self.start_abort_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

    # def long_running_task(self):
    #     self.status_var.set("Running...")
    #     for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.directory):
    #         if not self.running:
    #             break
    #         else:
    #             self.file_list.append(files)
    #             print(self.file_list)
    #     if self.running:
    #         self.status_var.set("Finished")
    #     else:
    #         self.status_var.set("Aborted")
    #     self.update_button()

    def back_end(self):
        self.status_var.set("Running...")
        file_list = long_running_task(self.running, self.directory)

        if self.running:
            self.status_var.set("Finished")
        else:
            self.status_var.set("Aborted")

        print("FINISHED with total List: ", file_list)
        self.update_button()

            
    def start_task(self):
        print(self.task_thread)
        if self.task_thread is None or not self.task_thread.is_alive():
            self.running = True
            self.status_var.set("Running...")
            self.task_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.back_end, daemon=True)
            #self.task_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.long_running_task, daemon=True)
            self.task_thread.start()
            self.anim_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.animate_status, daemon=True)
            self.anim_thread.start()  
            self.update_button()

            
    def abort_task(self):
        self.running = False
        self.file_list = []
        self.update_button()
        
    def animate_status(self):
        while self.running:
            for status in itertools.cycle(["Running.", "Running..", "Running..."]):
                if not self.running:
                    self.status_var.set("Aborted")
                    return
                self.status_var.set(status)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                
    def update_button(self):
        if self.running:
            self.start_abort_button.configure(text="Abort", command=self.abort_task)
        else:
            self.start_abort_button.configure(text="Start", command=self.start_task)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    APP(root)
    root.mainloop()

Other_python_skript:
import os

def long_running_task(running, directory):
    file_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        if not running:
            return[]
        else:
            file_list.append(files)
            print(file_list)
    return file_list



Forcefully killing threads is invariably a "Bad Idea" ™️. It is better to send the thread a message or set an event that makes it decide to exit of its own free will.

Your statement "if you pass a variable, you only reference the memory location" is true and that is the source of the problem. When python executes
file_list = long_running_task(self.running, self.directory)

it resolves self.running to a value (True, in your case) and passes an anonymous reference to that value to the function. The function binds that value the local variable running. self.running and running reference that same single True - which is the memory location you are talking about. The function references the value, it has no idea where that value came from.
If self.value is reassigned, it now references a different value in a different place in memory. running still references the original True because all it ever received was a reference to that location in memory.
There is more than one way to solve the problem, but an easy one is to have the function reference the namespace that holds the "running" variable. If the function looks up the variable in the namespace, it will get its current value, not the value it happened to get when the thread was first created. You can do this with the self variable. It references the APP instance namespace which as the "running" variable you want.
main.py
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import itertools
import time

from other_python_script import long_running_task

class APP():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Task Manager")

        self.running = False
        self.task_thread = None
        self.anim_thread = None
        self.status_var = tk.StringVar(value="Ready")

        self.directory = "Any directory with great depth"
        
        self.status_label = ttk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.status_var)
        self.status_label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.start_abort_button = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Start", command=self.start_task)
        self.start_abort_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

    # def long_running_task(self):
    #     self.status_var.set("Running...")
    #     for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.directory):
    #         if not self.running:
    #             break
    #         else:
    #             self.file_list.append(files)
    #             print(self.file_list)
    #     if self.running:
    #         self.status_var.set("Finished")
    #     else:
    #         self.status_var.set("Aborted")
    #     self.update_button()

    def back_end(self):
        self.status_var.set("Running...")
        file_list = long_running_task(self, self.directory) # changed

        if self.running:
            self.status_var.set("Finished")
        else:
            self.status_var.set("Aborted")

        print("FINISHED with total List: ", file_list)
        self.update_button()

            
    def start_task(self):
        print(self.task_thread)
        if self.task_thread is None or not self.task_thread.is_alive():
            self.running = True
            self.status_var.set("Running...")
            self.task_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.back_end, daemon=True)
            #self.task_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.long_running_task, daemon=True)
            self.task_thread.start()
            self.anim_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.animate_status, daemon=True)
            self.anim_thread.start()  
            self.update_button()

            
    def abort_task(self):
        self.running = False
        self.file_list = []
        self.update_button()
        
    def animate_status(self):
        while self.running:
            for status in itertools.cycle(["Running.", "Running..", "Running..."]):
                if not self.running:
                    self.status_var.set("Aborted")
                    return
                self.status_var.set(status)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                
    def update_button(self):
        if self.running:
            self.start_abort_button.configure(text="Abort", command=self.abort_task)
        else:
            self.start_abort_button.configure(text="Start", command=self.start_task)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    APP(root)
    root.mainloop()

other_python_script.py
import os

def long_running_task(app, directory): # changed
    file_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        if not app.running: # changed
            return[]
        else:
            file_list.append(files)
            print(file_list)
    return file_list


Try making running into a function:
Main:
def back_end(self):
    self.status_var.set("Running...")
    file_list = long_running_task((lambda: self.running), self.directory)

    if self.running:
        self.status_var.set("Finished")
    else:
        self.status_var.set("Aborted")

    print("FINISHED with total List: ", file_list)
    self.update_button()

Other file:
def long_running_task(running, directory):
    file_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        if not running():
            return[]
        else:
            file_list.append(files)
            print(file_list)
    return file_list

Answer based on info here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/

Just in case it helps, I have run your code on my Mac (Python 3.11.1) with both variants and got the same results and visual experience
<__main__.APP object at 0x106b4f210>
None
<Thread(Thread-1 (long_running_task), stopped daemon 123145515970560)>
<Thread(Thread-3 (long_running_task), stopped daemon 123145515970560)>


<__main__.APP object at 0x102523350>
None
<Thread(Thread-1 (back_end), stopped daemon 123145436504064)>
<Thread(Thread-3 (back_end), stopped daemon 123145436504064)>


Monitored process threads during execution. Thread is effectively killed by the abort button on either case
